# How to tell if Android startDiscovery() discovers BLE or Classic device

Tags: android-bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

When using Android's startDiscovery() method to discover Bluetooth devices one gets BOTH classic and Bluetooth Low Energy devices in the BroadcastReceiver action DEVICE_FOUND. The problem is that I cannot find a way to tell if the discovery came from a BTLE scan or a classic inquiry.

In many cases I can use the device type, but that doesn't work if the device is dual.

If it is dual, then in many cases I can look at the Device class. If the device class is not 7936 (unspecified), then I know it is a classic device. However, some classic devices are too lazy to put in a class value so it is reported as unspecified.

So now I am up against devices that are dual, responds to both inquiries and BTLE scans, and in the classic inquiry give unspecified. So I do not know if the action DEVICE_FOUND is from a BTLE device or a classic device. That means I cannot connect to the correct handler. If its an inquiry response and I try and connect BTLE, that will fail and vice versa.

The best solution in my opinion would be that Android allows one to specify that startDiscovery ONLY does inquiries (or BTLE scans) and not both.

In the absence of that, does anyone know how I could tell whether the discovery was from an inquiry or a BTLE advertisement WITHOUT trying to connect?

Comment: Can't you use `getType()` on the `BluetoothDevice` object?

Comment: If the device is not dual that works fine. The problem is when the device is both dual (so getType() returns dual or something indicating dual) and the device gives a class of unspecified during inquiry. ANDROID knows whether the discovery was through inquiry or advertisement. I wish they told us.

Comment: You could maybe start a BLE scan with no filters at the same time. Then if you don't get any results on BLE, assume it was a classic discovery.

Comment: I actually cycle through classic discovery and BTLE scans one after the other. THe problem is I support many health devices, many which are proprietary, that includes SPP, HDP and BTLE. This issue would be trivial if the startDiscovery() did NOT do BTLE scans under the hood at the same time. Its not all Android's fault. If the devices populated the informational fields correctly, it wouldn't be an issue. But some don't. I was just hoping that someone may know a way to check what the source was when its a DEVICE FOUND action. Probably is no way!